# How can I add a directory's contents to its own context menu in windows explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, context-menu

I want to add a context menu item for folders that opens a sub menu containing the folder's contents: files and sub folders.  Ideally, those sub folders would act the same way, opening another sub menu containing it's files and folders.

The ideal end result is a fast and (sometimes) easy way to navigate through a directory structure via a right-click.

Should it be important, I want to do this for Windows 7 and Server 2008R2.  Anyone have ideas?

Comment: If there were a 1000 items in the directory, this solution would be a problem.

Comment: yes, it would be.  There's no denying that anyone using this would have to take a little responsibility when using it

Comment: Alternatively, it would be very nice if no more than 50 records were returned to the sub menu.  But I honestly think that's outside the scope of manipulating windows.  Seems more like it would require altering Windows to achieve this.  That said, I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: If it exists, it is well hidden. But the internet is a big place. You could write one with C++ :)